# Mysqli querying error: Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, DB given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Struggling to understand how to get the ID of the newly inserted row.

This is my procedural mysqli connection and SQL INSERT statement:

```
class DB {
    
    var $conn;
    function __construct($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $dbport = 0000) {
        $this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $dbport );         
    }
 
// Run a query
    public function query($sql) {
        return $this->conn->query($sql);
    }

// Clean incoming data
    public function clean($data) {
        return $this->conn->real_escape_string($data);
    }    
}
    
define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_USER","myusername");
define("DB_PASS","mypass");
define("DB_NAME","mydbname");
define("db",new DB(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME));

$sql = db->query("INSERT INTO my_table (field_one, field_two, field_three) VALUES ( 'test1', 'test2', 'test3')");
```

I thought I could then do something ([like this](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-php/mysql-get-last-id.html)):

```
if (mysqli_query(db, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id(db);
    echo "New record created. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error(db);
}
```

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, DB given in /var/www/vhosts/***.****.com/httpdocs/admin/test.php:36
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/***.****.com/httpdocs/admin/test.php(36): mysqli_query() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/***.****.com/httpdocs/admin/test.php on line 36 line 36
```

This would be the first line of the second block: `if (mysqli_query(db, $sql)) {`

---

**Where am I going wrong?**  Would really appreciate an explanation w/ what and why?

Also might be a dumb question, but in the examples I've read online -none of which match my connection set up exactly- none mention whether the name of the column for ID matters?  My format is"table_id" rather than just "id", and it is set to auto-increment.

Comment: One of the places you're going wrong is using `real_escape_string` to sanitize and not using [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: And here's the [Manual on num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) --  `$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;`

Comment: Your two code blocks appear to be entirely unrelated. Not sure what is going on there. The "DB" class seems to be a largely pointless wrapper around mysqli though which doesn't seem to actually add any functionality or save the caller any meaningful time or code

Comment: `Where am I going wrong?`...well you haven't actually told us what issue occurred when you tried to run the code? Was there a specific error? `mysqli_query(db` looks wrong though - I doubt you have a constant named `db`. You would need to put the mysqli connection object as the first argument to that function.

Comment: `none mention whether the name of the column for ID matters`...because it doesn't. It just needs to be an autoincrement field which is also the Primary Key of the table

Comment: @ADyson they _do_ have a constant named `db`, which is _unhinged_ in itself. [This is allowed in PHP>=8.1]

Comment: @ADyson thank you -the constant db is there. The reason for the first block is so you can see how the connection code / insert statement affect each other. The error I got was Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, DB given in /var/www/vhosts/***.****.com/httpdocs/admin/test.php:36 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/***.****.com/httpdocs/admin/test.php(36): mysqli_query() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/***.****.com/httpdocs/admin/test.php on line 36

line 36 would be the first line of the second block: 
if (mysqli_query(db, $sql)) {

Comment: Well obviously the mysqli_query function expects to receive a `mysqli` connection object, but you've passed it an instance of your `DB` class, which it doesn't understand. You actually need the `$conn` object from within it. Again the `DB` class is primarily a hindrance here

Comment: The most horrifying thing about this question is real_escape_string **doesn't clean anything**

Answer (score 4):

It would be helpful if you actually included the error message, but the problem is that your DB class is neither an extension of the Mysqli class, nor does it implement a relevant interface, and as such you *cannot* simply drop it into functions that expect a Mysqli object. As ADyson already mentioned your wrapper class is unnecessary and actively getting in your way here, as it will many other places.

Ditch the wrapper class and use the Mysqli object directly.

Also, global state is generally a bad idea, especially for DB connections. It allows "spooky action at a distance", aka code that appears completely unrelated having side-effects via shared objects in the global namespace, as well as handcuffing you to only ever being able to use a single DB connection without making significant rewrites.

Generally it is best to pass a DB connection into the call or object that requires it, eg:

```
$db = new Mysqli(...);

foo($db, $arg1, $arg2);

$f = new Foo($db, ...);
```

Comment: thank you @Sammitch - this is helpful information.  New to PHP and someone wrote it this way who seemed to know what they were doing.  The error I got was Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, DB given in /var/www/vhosts/***.****.com/httpdocs/admin/test.php:36 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/***.****.com/httpdocs/admin/test.php(36): mysqli_query() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/***.****.com/httpdocs/admin/test.php on line 36 line 36 would be the first line of the second block: if (mysqli_query(db, $sql)) { –

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, your code is destined to fail regardless of the changes below, but let me explain why you're seeing the problem you encountered before explaining why this still wouldn't work.

---

## The Error

Your `DB` class isn't a type of `mysqli`, but this can be fixed by changing `class DB` to:

```
class DB extends mysqli
```

Here's a breakdown of what's happening:

```
<?php

// Defines a new class, DB, which is type DB.
class DB {}

// Defines "db" as an instance of the DB class, still type DB.
define("db",new DB(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME));

// This is trying to pass "db" as the first argument to mysqli_query().
if (mysqli_query(db, $sql)) {}
```

The problem is that `mysqli_query` is expecting the following:

```
function mysqli_query(
    mysqli $mysql,
    string $query,
    int|null $result_mode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT
): bool|mysqli_result
```

As you can see, the first parameter expects type `mysqli`, whether instanced directly with `new mysqli()` or indirectly with `extends mysqli`. The fact that you've instanced a `new mysqli` inside of `DB` doesn't make a difference, you could copy the entire `mysqli` class but if you name it `DB` it's still going to be typed in that way without an extension.

Once you make this change, your argument should be accepted.

---

## The Problem

The underlying issue is that your `DB` class still won't be appropriate for executing `mysqli` class code.

If you take a look at the [mysqli class docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), you'll notice that your class isn't appropriately designed to contain your connection information and will ultimately fail because the function you're calling can't access `$conn`. Your wrapper works for very basic use-cases to call the `query()` and `clean()` methods, but that's all. It doesn't actually inject the necessary information required for the parent `mysqli` class to function properly.

Technically, you could remedy this by exposing `$conn` with a getter:

```
<?php
class DB {
    // ...other stuff
    public function getConn() {
        return $this->conn;
    }
}

mysqli_query(db->getConn(), $sql);
```

Or by using the `__toString()` magic method which will always treat `db` as the connection when you aren't calling other methods like `db->query()`.

```
<?php
class DB {
    // ...other stuff
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->conn;
    }
}

mysqli_query(db, $sql);
```

However, this seems really impractical unless you have some reason to hide the rest of the `mysqli` functionality.

#### Wrappers

This would *almost* be appropriate for creating a database wrapper containing logic for interacting with functions like `mysqli_query` inside of its own class, but it doesn't seem the be the goal you have in mind.

A wrapper is useful because it allows you to implement logic in one place. You're using functions outside of this class requiring `mysqli` though, so it doesn't actually aid you in this situation. However, a corrected example could be something like this:

```
<?php
class DB {
    // ...other stuff
    public function db_query($sql) {
        return mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
    }
}

// Now, if you change databases you can just edit db_query.
db->db_query($sql);
```

#### Child Classes

The **correct** way to build a class in this manner would be to inject your `__construct` arguments into the parent class, but since you're overwriting the `query()` method to call `$conn`, this would also result in a broken instance of your database class.

An example of how you'd correctly build a child class would look something like this:

```
<?php
class DB extends mysqli {
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $database, $port = 3306) {
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $database, $port);
    }

    // New custom methods go here.
}

// Now a fully functional mysqli child!
$db = new DB(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

My recommendation would be to just create a direct instance through `$db = new mysqli()` instead of going through any of these abstraction processes. Although abstracting classes this way has its uses, since you're still in the learning stages I think it's adding extra, unnecessary complexity.